# Show only odd lines with cat

Tags: bash

HI,

probably is this something very easy, but I do not get the point now. In Linux, shell, given a text file, how can I do something like,  cat filename so I only see the first line, the third line, 5, 7, 9 and so on?

if not with cat, with another command

Thanks

Answer (score 43):

Using `awk`: `awk 'NR % 2 == 0' filename`

Edit: removed `{print}`, as shown in ghostdog74's answer and commented on by Roberto Bonvallet.

Comment: `{print}` is the default action, so `awk 'NR % 2 == 0' < myfile` is enough.

Comment: @roberto, don't need the input redirection.

Comment: Just as a note, this shows even lines (where the first line is 1) and odd lines (if you think of the first line as 0). Replace `2 == 0` with `2 == 1` for the opposite.

Comment: Worked perfectly with pipe `cat filename | awk 'NR % 2 == 1'` (for odd lines). A third-party program was adding an unwanted newline after each line, so I piped its output directly into awk for cleanup.

Answer (score 13):

Or something like

```
sed -n 'p;n' filename
```

For explanation look-up the man page for `sed`.

Comment: This is the portable `sed` version that slipped my mind.

Comment: you can easily skip lines upfront with `sed -n '1d;p;n'` for the even lines for example

Answer (score 7):

Use sed:

```
sed -n 1~2p filename
```

Comment: This is a GNU extension. It may not work systems where GNU `sed` is not the default.

Comment: True but should work with most flavours of Linux

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried  "sed --posix -n 1~2p filename" and that seems to work as well. The --posix is supposed to remove support for gnu extensions.

Comment: The GNU `sed` manual http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html#Addresses says “first~step  This GNU extension…”. It does not mention `--posix`. When I try `gsed --posix -n 1~2p` (GNU sed 4.2.1), I get `gsed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: ‘~’`.

Comment: Ok.. makes sense. Dont know whats wrong with my sed. I'm using cygwin, so that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{if(NR%2!=0)print}' myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways you can do it with awk

```
$ awk '{getline;print}' file # the equivalent of the selected sed answer
$ awk 'NR%2==0' file
```

OR with just the shell

```
i=1; while read -r line; do [ $((i++ % 2)) -eq 0 ] && echo $line; done <"file"
```

Comment: Simpler (and doesn't mangle some data) `while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; read -r line; done <file`

Answer (score 0):

A simple search in Google shows this link: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/academic/write-odd-even-line-file/

You only need to tweak it a little bit.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this (doesn't seem to work on Mac OS X), but GNU sed supports `first~step` as an address selection, so for example:

`sed -n 1~2p file`

would start at the first line and print every other line after that.

Comment: Right, this is a GNU extension. Mac OS X uses a BSD `sed` in the base installation.

Answer (score 0):

It's really as simple as `sed 'n;d' filename`...

Or if you don't want to rely on en external command :

```
while read; do echo $REPLY; read; done < filename
```

Answer (score -2):

Unable to test, found a link:
[cat -n $1 | grep "$ODDRE" | cut -b 8- > oddfile.$$](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/academic/write-odd-even-line-file/)

Comment: You missed out the most important thing... what `ODDRE` is set to.

But that answer will only work if the file is less than a million lines.

Answer (score -2):

You can use these commands for require result

**awk 'NR%2 == 1'**

**sed -ne '1~2p'**

Comment: -1. This duplicates answers from almost 10 years ago, minor differences are not explained at all. And why is `ls -l` here?